# Domain Access and One.com hosting (funny subdomain rewrite)

Tags: path-aliases, .htaccess, domain-access, subsites

I have a D7 installation that uses Domain Access to distinguish between a main website `example.com` and a minisite `event.example.com`. They share the same document root / Drupal installation and the same database. I use Domain Path to have subdomain-specific aliases.

This worked fine, until I decided to move this website to a webspace at One.com. They do this thing were you can create a subdomain just by creating a directory in the document root. So `/folder/` can automatically be accesssed in three ways:

- `http://folder.example.com/`
- `http://example.com/folder/`
- `http://www.example.com/folder/`

By default, there is an `A` wildcard DNS-record for `*.example.com`.

The relevant part of my `/.htaccess` currently looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  #strip www.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  #pass all requests that do not refer to files to index.php
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(event\.)?example\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This messes up all static files on `event.example.com`. When `http://event.example.com/sites/default/files/css/css_*.css` is accessed, Apache tries to find an `/event/` directory, which doesn't exist and gives a 404.

I attempted to fix this by symlinking `/event/` to `/`. Now the static files work, but domain paths on `event.example.com` no longer work (they all give 404s) and links tend to get rewritten to `http://event.example.com/event/somelink`.

I also tried to fix this by adding the following, but that didn't help.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/event(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://event.example.com%1 [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my symlink from `/event/` to `/` was correct, but that I additionally needed to specify `RewriteBase /` to fix the link rewriting part.